# How to set more than one font sizes for a legend item in a QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer

I am looking for a possibility to set a second font size for one legend item in QGIS (2.8.1) Printcomposer. For every item (name of a plant) I need a smaler expression in brackets (name in latin). Is this possible, if yes, how?

Comment: I don't think this is possible... yet. It would be a nice to be able to format legend items texts.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to convert to graphics --> ungroup several times and then use tags <> in the text box to set different text sizes. A lot of work, though.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to convert the legend to graphics in QGIS. I used to do this in ArcGIS sometimes.

Comment: That is sad, this feature would be very handy

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible on the newest version of QGIS 3.30, as announced [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/#print-layouts).